# Custom File field to capture image from webcam in Laravel nova

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

I am new to Laravel Nova and i want to upload an avatar either from computer or capture from webcamera. As for now i have created a conditional dependency select field to hide and show elements using [this package](https://github.com/epartment/nova-dependency-container). I have come across [webcamjs](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) and i want to know how would i implment this custom action.

[image]

I have two options "Capture from webcamera" and "Upload from computer". I only have this "Upload from computer" for now and it works fine. What i want to have is to capture the image from webcam and load the avatar field.

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
        return [
            ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),

            Text::make('Full Name')->rules('required'),

            Select::make('Upload Avatar', 'upload_avatar_method')->options([
                0 => 'Capture from Webcamera',
                1 => 'Upload from Computer',
            ])->displayUsingLabels()->rules('required'),


            NovaDependencyContainer::make([
                Avatar::make('Avatar','avatar')
                    ->disk('public')
                    ->path('employees/'. $request->user()->id)
                    ->storeAs(function (Request $request) {
                        return 'avatar.'.$request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    })
                    ->rules('required')
                    ->thumbnail(function ($value, $disk) {
                        return $value
                                    ? Storage::disk($disk)->url($value)
                                    : null;
                    })->hideFromIndex(),
            ])->dependsOn('upload_avatar_method', 1),

        ];
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this yet? It's all going to be client-side JS code.

Comment: unfortunately i am not much proficient with handling all custom via client-seide JS @miken32. I didn't much understand how to have custom code with nova, any sample code or an article would be very beneficial for refering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There are several methods to solve the problem.*

**IMPORTANT**: I do not recommend using the [WebcamJS](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) package because it is an unmaintained package and there are other viable alternatives. You can fork the package and fix any errors but that would be more work.

---

**Option #1 (Maybe the best choice for you)**

My advice is to create a custom field that extends "Avatar" or "File" and add the "Capture from webcam" option. You can use one of these packages that I link below (more up-to-date than WebcamJS) quickly and easily.

---

**Option #2 (Easy 'n shared!)**

Another possible, even simpler approach is to create a standalone custom "Webcam" field. You will still need the [Nova Field Dependency Container](https://github.com/epartment/nova-dependency-container) package but your custom field could share it with the community in a standalone way.

---

[How to create a custom field in laravel nova](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/fields.html)

---

Alternative packages to WebcamJS:

- [Multicorder](https://github.com/bwinkers/multicorder)
- [VueWebCam](https://github.com/vinceg/vue-web-cam)
- [EasyVueCamera](https://github.com/farhadnowzari/easy-vue-camera)
- [VueMediaRecorder](https://github.com/YovelBecker/vue-media-recorder)

Choose the package that is most useful for you!
I hope to be proved helpful!

Comment: Thank you for the extensive reply. I tried coupling with [Uppy](https://uppy.io/docs/webcam/) and i did not know to add standalone custom codes. I went with creating a custom field which you had recommended. There is so much for me to learn how to deal with custom fields.

Comment: Custom fields are probably Laravel Nova's strong point. I took a look at the Uppy package and I must say it is really well done. Personally I tried to create a custom field to use the webcam, it is not very easy as a first task but once you do it you will understand how comfortable they are. The packages you create are also ready to be shared with the community in just a few steps.